# Third law of Kepler

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

***I can not find any solution to this exercise on the internet.***

> Calculate the mean radius of the orbit of a fictitious planet X,
>   expressed in kilometers and UA, so that its orbital period is 1.9x10 ^
>   8 (seconds). In which region of the solar system would the planet X be
>   located?

***Problems:***

*1) My main problem is that I do not know if I should convert seconds to days, years or what?*

*2)  Also, if I calculate it with seconds, the result of the radius will be in kilometers, meters, or what?*

**Could someone please explain how it works correctly?**

Comment: This looks like homework, so just a hint: Kepler's third law is a proportionality relationship. You need a reference. A very handy reference is the Earth, which orbits the Sun in one year at a mean distance of one AU.

Comment: Hello @EduardoSebastian and welcome to Physics SE! Please note that homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. We don't answer homework or worked example type questions.

Comment: Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: I do not look for my homework, sorry, if I express badly, if the 3 laws, but my teacher never explained, that if giving me in seconds, I must transform it, or not

Comment: If gives you what you put in. Put SI-units in (on all variables and constants) and you get SI-units out. That's always a fool-proof method. Then afterwards convert from that to the actual unit you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the question is most easily achieved by using ratios as @David Hammen mentioned in his comment. The ratio would be $$\frac{r_1\ ^3}{T_1\ ^2} = \frac{r_2\ ^3}{T_2\ ^2}$$This leaves the units that you calculate for $r_2$ to be *completely* dependant on the units you choose for $r_1$. For example, as David said using the earth and $r_1 = 1AU$, then the answer that you get for $r_2$ will also be given in $AU$. It doesn't matter what units you choose to do the time in $($could be in terms of how long it takes to boil the average egg, for example$)$ as long as you keep them consistent between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i cant understand the difference between compare or use the equation = 1

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Well the earth is $1AU$ away from the sun, so that gives a value of $r_1\ ^3 = 1$, and we know that the earth has an orbital period of a year, which is equal to approx $31,536,000$ seconds. From this you can calculate a value of the planet X's radius from the time period given, that being $1.9\times 10^8$

Comment: You don't need to change the units you've been given, unless you want to state the units of the planet you're comparing it to in a different way. For example if you want to keep it simple as $T_1$ = one year, then you'll have to state the time period given in terms of years, but as you're given a time period in terms of seconds you should put $T_1$, or the earth orbit time, in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert time to seconds (since second is the base unit of time in the International System of Units (SI)).

If you use SI units, your answer will be in SI units. (so the radius will be in meters, since it's the base unit of length)

Comment: but the exercise is already in seconds, you can explain more please

Comment: because my teacher said me, that the result is in UA, and after i need to multiply by 1.5x10^8 to give me in kilometers

Comment: We have Kepler's third law $T^2=kr^3$. Since $k=\frac{4\pi^2}{GM_{sun}}$, where $M_{sun}=1.98\cdot 10^{30} kg$ and $G$ is the gravitational constant $G=6.67 \cdot 10^{-11} m^3s^{-2}kg^{-1}$. So, in the Solar system $k=2.99\cdot 10^{-19} s^2m^{-3}$, and now we can compute the radius using $r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{T^2}{k}}$.